# HTTP Error When Uploading Images with HTTPS?

Tags: uploads, https

When uploading an image in WP with regular http, everything works fine.

When uploading an image with HTTPS I get an error that says - "HTTP error." in red.

Why is the HTTPS causing this problem? How do I fix it?

thank you!

Edit, uploading images with HTTPS in WP admin works but does not work via the theme/front-end? I guess this is a theme issue?

Answer (score -1):

Adding this to my theme's functions.php solved this same problem for me:

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

Comment: Please explain how it works and *why* it should help the OP. Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution here but I don't know how it works. It did for me :) [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-error-when-uploading-images-but-not-all-failing)